# Shiro, hash, salt, database

Tags: java, database, shiro

I have a SHA-256 **hash** of the password stored in my SQL Express database. In the same table, I have the corresponding **salt**. Both were generated with java code in the pas. Now, using Shiro, I wish to connect to my database, retrieve the hash and salt and compare it, to the credentials supplied in the login page. My problem is that I allways receive **IncorrectCredentialsException**.

I am sure that the program so far connects to the database as it returns an error stating that the user does not exist if the username is incorrect. Also I see from the db logs, that the program queries the database.

```
[main]
# specify login page
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /application/Login
authc.usernameParam = user
authc.passwordParam = pass
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
authc.successUrl  = /application/IndexServ.jsp

# password matcher
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

# database conn
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.resourceRef = true 
ds.resourceName = jdbc/application_data/server_startup
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource

# realms
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
sha256Matcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
sha256Matcher.hashIterations = 100
sha256Matcher.hashSalted = true

jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT UserPasswordHash, UserPasswordSalt FROM USERS WHERE UserName = ?
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher
```

I suspect that the comparison made is not made for SHA-256. Is it even possible to use the default passwordMatcher to authenticate users with hash and salt written in table?

Comment: Are you sure the hashing function is the same as your original source? Same number of iterations etc?

Comment: Hello Brian. As my collegue pointed out, it only does one itteration. I've edited the setting hashIterations = 1.  Still no success. But regarding the hashing function, what do you mean? In my database I have the SHA-256 hash of the password and its salt in a different column. Isn't this enough for shiro to take the input password from the user, salt it with the salt from the database and than compare the generated hash to the saved hash?

Comment: @BrianDemers I also added the following code: `SimpleAuthenticationInfo sAi = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(); sAi.setCredentials(token.getCredentials()); System.out.println("SAI salt: " + sAi.getCredentialsSalt()); System.out.println("SAI credentials: " + sAi.getCredentials()); `
I get the following output: `SAI salt: null
SAI credentials: [C@4beba155`

Comment: Take a look at this test, it should have similar setting. https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JDBCRealmTest.java#L144     (I’m mobile currently, but keep me posted, and I’ll take another look if you are still stuck)

Comment: @BrianDemers thank you for your help, but unfortunately I did not succeed. Please correct me if I am wrong on my logic. In the shiro.ini file, I set the connection to my database and construct my query. When I submit the login form, shiro takes my username and password. It connects to the db via jndi and performs the query (I see the response: salt and hash in wireshark both correct). Bellow is my java code:

Comment: ``Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");``  
``SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();``  
``Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();``  
``UsernamePasswordToken token = null;``  
``String loginUsername = Razno.getRequestParameter(request, "loginUsername");``  
``String loginPassword = Razno.getRequestParameter(request, "loginPassword");``  
``token = new UsernamePasswordToken(loginUsername, loginPassword, true);
currentUser.login(token);``

Comment: When i perform currentUser.login(token) I get the result IncorrectCredentialsException. If I change the username to something that does not exist, I get UnknownAccountException. Is there a possibility to print line what shiro compares the hash of the password to? Do I need to construct a custom realm to see this?

Comment: Update. If I set shiro.ini without sha256Matcher and as a user I enter the hash of the corresponding user from the database I get a successful connection. I suspect the problem is with the settings of sha256Matcher. Do I need to specify anywhere that the matcher has to use the salt stored in the database?